# Table of Contents different margins on first and subsequent pages

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I am writing my doctoral thesis using the mcgilletdclass template that I downloaded on-line. For the most part, I have been able to make modifications to get a more desirable template; however, I am having problems getting a consistent one inch margin on the top page of the Table of Contents/List of Tables/List of Figures. Specifically, the margin is 2 inches at the top of the first page of the Table of Contents, for example, and then changes to 1 inch for the subsequent pages. In my opinion, this makes the section look inconsistent and sloppy.

These margin specification might be included in the mcgilletd.class.cls file, which can be found at:
https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/mcgilletdclassmine.cls

I have tried some modification to no avail, including using the attempting to use the tocloft package. However, to my limited .tex knowledge, that package seems to be incompatible with the class file I am using as I get errors when I try to use it. In addition, at this point I do not change to a different .cls since my other modifications have worked wonderfully.

I am including a mwe outlining my problem, which requires the .cls file that I provided a link to earlier. I have provided annotations showing what I have tried to do, including commenting out a couple of options that I have already tried (see immediately before \tableofcontents %)

```
\documentclass[12pt,Bold,landscape]{mcgilletdclass}
%\usepackage[%
%  backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
% backend=biber    % Use biber
%]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,url=false, isbn=false, doi=false,         style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear, sorting=nyt,dashed=FALSE, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}


\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\onehalfspacing



% The following code came with the mcgilletd thesis .tex file. I have made some adjustments, but I am not sure what the following commands really mean.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Have you configured your TeX system for proper  %%
%% page alignment? See the McGillETD documentation %%
%% for two methods that can be used to control     %%
%% page alignment. One method is demonstrated      %%
%% below. See documentation and the ufalign.tex    %%
%% file for instructions on how to adjust these    %%
%% parameters.                                     %%


\setlength{\textheight}{\topskip}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{33\baselineskip}%
\ifthenelse{\value{QZ@ptcnt}=11}{%
\addtolength{\textheight}{3\baselineskip}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\value{QZ@ptcnt}=10}{%
\addtolength{\textheight}{9\baselineskip}}{}%  

        %%

%\makeindex[keylist]
%\makeindex[abbr]

%% Input any special commands below
%\newcommand{\Kron}[1]{\ensuremath{\delta_{K}\left(#1\right)}}
\listfiles%

\begin{document}
%\newgeometry{left=1in, bottom=1in, top=0.0in, right=1in}
%Table of contents add extra space

\TOCHeading{\large{Table of Contents}}%
\LOTHeading{\large{List of Tables}}%
\LOFHeading{\large{List of Figures}}%

% The following three commands are ones that I have tried to change the top margin of the first page of the Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables; however, none have worked to the desired effect.

%\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1in}}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
%\newgeometry{left=1in, bottom=1in, top=1in, right=1in}
\tableofcontents %
\listoftables %
\listoffigures %


\doublespacing
\chapter{Problem}An example from my thesis with a Table of Contents, List of Tables and List of Figures. When my actual thesis is compiled, the first page of the Table of Contents, List of Tables/Figures has a 2 inch top margin, whereas the subsequent pages have 1 inch margins. I would like to make all top margins an inch.
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\chapter{Example chapter}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\chapter{Example showing 1 inch margin. First page of Table of Contents has 2 inch margin}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\end{document}
```

I would be happy to provide other information if need be.

Comment: Load option `showframe` when loading package `geometry` and check the margins. By the way, why loading geometry to get a user friendly interface, and then overwrite it with low-level mumbo jumbo? The template is full of mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: I have loaded the option and see that there is an extra inch added to the top of the first page of the TOC/LOT/and LOF, but not the subsequent pages of these three sections.

Comment: The same space is added for *each* chapter in your document.

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you look at the following PDF document <https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fe016b34a287a85245b4ce/v/1/pdf?inline=true&name=McGill%20University%20Thesis> for the Mcgill thesis, the same inconsistency also exists.

Comment: That is by far an inconsistency, this is by design. Commonly, package `titlesec` is used to customize the appearance of chapter titles.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\BigMargin}{}` I really would not use this template.

Comment: @Johannes_B this is the answer.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  After spending months making adjustments to this template, I have have committed a lot of time to get it to a point that I like what I have created. That being said, I agree that it is not worthwhile using and have already warned others against using it - they are better off either creating their own or using another student's template.

Comment: Please add a clear comment to your modified version that it indeed *is* a modified version, add the date and your name/pseudonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class has some code to ensure a two inch space, which is added before the chapter title is typeset.

```
%%    Creating a 2 inch margin
\newlength{\BigLength}%
\setlength{\BigLength}{0pt}%
\newcommand{\BigMargin}{\hspace*{1in}\normalfont\normalsize%
\settoheight{\QZ@TempLength}{()}%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace*{1in}%
\vspace*{\QZ@TempLength}\vspace*{\BigLength} \\}%
```

If you redefine command `\BigMargin` to do nothing, your problem seems to be gone.

```
\renewcommand{\BigMargin}{}
```